# Starting GATE with two pipelines

Tags: initialization, init, pipeline, gate

I want to start GATE from an external system managed by a U/I. I'm not in charge of the U/I development. I need to know if GATE can be started/initialized externally with TWO PIPELINES. Can this be done? And if so, how?

I suppose using the "Gate.init();" command to initialize/start GATE, but then how do I start two separate pipelines?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running GATE through the Gate.init(), then you can easily load two Controller objects:

```
CorpusController pipeline1 = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(new File("savedState.xgapp"));

CorpusController pipeline2 = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(new File("another.xgapp"));
Corpus corpus = Factory.newCorpus("web corpus");
pipeline1.setCorpus(corpus);
pipeline2.setCorpus(corpus); // I don't see why, but you may need two different corpora
```

Then you can execute any of them depending on your logic:

```
Document doc = Factory.newDocument("Text from my web form");
corpus.add(doc);

// if some condition
pipeline1.execute();

// remember to clean up resources:
corpus.clear();
Factory.deleteResource(doc);
```

However, if you're doing a web application I would recommend reading [this whole chapter](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html) and using what's most convenient in your case.

I personally prefer the Spring application, following the example in module 8 from [the GATE training materials](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseJune2013/). If you're familiar with Spring it should be easy for you to configure two different pipelines to use in your services.